# Background Service in iPhone

Tags: iphone, background-service

I wan to know that How can I implement background services in iPhone 4.0 or later so that even if I close my application it keeps on running in the background and keeps on updating my GUI Text etc

I am new in iPhone that i why i am posting that question in that portal.

Please Help me with some code and guidelines.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are new to iPhone development, you should read iPhone application programming guide provided in the documentation of iPhone SDK. This will clear most of the basic questions.

Comment: nice .. thanks i will check that out for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the iOS does not have background services. You can make you app run in background but only if it is a VOIP client, Audio player or will respond to location changes.

Comment: Can i do it like.. i Am uploading some data... onto my web server.. which take 4 -5 minutes. now it us being uploaded in a separate thread. if i close my application it goes to background and then it will keep on uploading my data.. will it ?? or it will top that thread as well ??

Comment: Yes you can start long running thread in the background, they do have a maximum of 10 minutes of running time.